# Efficient way to allot the next available VM

Tags: java, cloud, allocation

The method `getNextAvailableVm()` allots virtual machines for a particular data center in a round-robin fashion. *(The integer returned by this method is the machine allotted)*

In a data center there could be virtual machines with different set of configurations. For example :

```
5 VMs with 1024 memory
4 VMs with 512 memory

Total : 9 VMs
```

For this data center a machine with 1024 memory will get task 2 times as compared to machine with 512 memory.

So machines for this data center are returned by the `getNextAvailableVm()` in the following way :

```
0 0 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 6 7 8
```

This is the current way, the machines are being returned.But there is a problem.

There could be cases, when a particular machine is busy and cannot be allotted the task.Instead the next machine available with the highest memory must be allotted the task.I have not been able to implement this.

For example :

```
0 (allotted first time)
0 (to be allotted the second time)
but if 0 is busy..
allot 1 if 1 is not busy
next circle check if 0 is busy
if not busy allot 0  (only when machine numbered 0 has not handled the requests it is entitled to handle)
if busy, allot the next
```

`cloudSimEventFired` method in the following class is called when ever the machine gets freed or is allotted.

```
    public class TempAlgo extends VmLoadBalancer implements CloudSimEventListener {

    /**
     * Key : Name of the data center
     * Value : List of objects of class 'VmAllocationUIElement'.
     */
    private  Map<String,LinkedList<DepConfAttr>> confMap = new HashMap<String,LinkedList<DepConfAttr>>();
    private Iterator<Integer> availableVms = null;
    private DatacenterController dcc;
    private boolean sorted = false;
    private int currentVM;
    private boolean calledOnce = false;
    private boolean indexChanged = false;
    private LinkedList<Integer> busyList = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    private Map<String,LinkedList<AlgoAttr>> algoMap = new HashMap<String, LinkedList<AlgoAttr>>();
    private Map<String,AlgoHelper> map = new HashMap<String,AlgoHelper>();  
    private Map<String,Integer> vmCountMap = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

    public TempAlgo(DatacenterController dcb) {
        confMap = DepConfList.dcConfMap;
        this.dcc = dcb;
        dcc.addCloudSimEventListener(this);
        if(!this.calledOnce) {
            this.calledOnce = true;
            // Make a new map using dcConfMap that lists 'DataCenter' as a 'key' and 'LinkedList<AlgoAttr>' as 'value'.
            Set<String> keyst =DepConfList.dcConfMap.keySet();
            for(String dataCenter : keyst) {
                LinkedList<AlgoAttr> tmpList = new LinkedList<AlgoAttr>();
                LinkedList<DepConfAttr> list = dcConfMap.get(dataCenter);
                int totalVms = 0;
                for(DepConfAttr o : list) {
                    tmpList.add(new AlgoAttr(o.getVmCount(), o.getMemory()/512, 0));
                    totalVms = totalVms + o.getVmCount();
                }
                Temp_Algo_Static_Var.algoMap.put(dataCenter, tmpList);
                Temp_Algo_Static_Var.vmCountMap.put(dataCenter, totalVms);
            }
            this.algoMap = new HashMap<String, LinkedList<AlgoAttr>>(Temp_Algo_Static_Var.algoMap);
            this.vmCountMap = new HashMap<String,Integer>(Temp_Algo_Static_Var.vmCountMap);
            this.map = new HashMap<String,AlgoHelper>(Temp_Algo_Static_Var.map);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getNextAvailableVm() {
        synchronized(this) {
            String dataCenter = this.dcc.getDataCenterName();
            int totalVMs = this.vmCountMap.get(dataCenter);
            AlgoHelper ah = (AlgoHelper)this.map.get(dataCenter);
            int lastIndex = ah.getIndex();
            int lastCount = ah.getLastCount();
            LinkedList<AlgoAttr> list = this.algoMap.get(dataCenter);
            AlgoAttr aAtr = (AlgoAttr)list.get(lastIndex);
            indexChanged = false;
            if(lastCount < totalVMs)  {
                if(aAtr.getRequestAllocated() % aAtr.getWeightCount() == 0) {
                    lastCount = lastCount + 1;
                    this.currentVM = lastCount;
                    if(aAtr.getRequestAllocated() == aAtr.getVmCount() * aAtr.getWeightCount()) {
                        lastIndex++;
                        if(lastIndex != list.size()) {
                            AlgoAttr aAtr_N = (AlgoAttr)list.get(lastIndex);
                            aAtr_N.setRequestAllocated(1);
                            this.indexChanged = true;
                        }
                        if(lastIndex == list.size()) {
                            lastIndex = 0;
                            lastCount = 0;
                            this.currentVM = lastCount;
                            AlgoAttr aAtr_N = (AlgoAttr)list.get(lastIndex);
                            aAtr_N.setRequestAllocated(1);
                            this.indexChanged = true;

                        }
                    }
                }
                if(!this.indexChanged) {
                    aAtr.setRequestAllocated(aAtr.getRequestAllocated() + 1);
                }

                this.map.put(dataCenter, new AlgoHelper(lastIndex, lastCount)); 

                //System.out.println("Current VM : " + this.currentVM + " for data center : " + dataCenter);
                return this.currentVM;
            }}

            System.out.println("--------Before final return statement---------");
            return 0;

    }   

    @Override
    public void cloudSimEventFired(CloudSimEvent e) {
        if(e.getId() == CloudSimEvents.EVENT_CLOUDLET_ALLOCATED_TO_VM) {
            int vmId = (Integer) e.getParameter(Constants.PARAM_VM_ID);
                    busyList.add(vmId);

            System.out.println("+++++++++++++++++++Machine with vmID : " + vmId + " attached");
        }else if(e.getId() == CloudSimEvents.EVENT_VM_FINISHED_CLOUDLET) {
            int vmId = (Integer) e.getParameter(Constants.PARAM_VM_ID);
                            busyList.remove(vmId);
            //System.out.println("+++++++++++++++++++Machine with vmID : " + vmId + " freed");
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code, all the lists are already sorted with the highest memory first.The whole idea is to balance the memory by allocating more tasks to a machine with higher memory.

Each time a machine is allotted request allocated is incremented by one.Each set of machines have a weight count attached to it, which is calculated by dividing `memory_allotted` by `512`.

The method `getNextAvailableVm()` is called by multiple threads at a time. For 3 Data Centers 3 threads will simultaneously call `getNextAva...()` but on different class objects.The data center returned by the statement `this.dcc.getDataCenterName()` in the same method is returned according to the *data center broker policy* selected earlier.

**How do I make sure that the machine I am currently returning is free and if the machine is not free I allot the next machine with highest memory available.I also have to make sure that the machine that is entitled to process `X` tasks, does process `X` tasks even that machine is currently busy.**

This is a general description of the data structure used here :

[image]

The code of this class is hosted [here on github](https://github.com/suhailgupta03/cld_an_progress/blob/master/src/cloudsim/ext/datacenter/TempAlgo.java).

This is the link for the [complete project on github](https://github.com/suhailgupta03/cld_an_progress).

Most of the data structures/classes used here are inside [this package](https://github.com/suhailgupta03/cld_an_progress/tree/master/src/temp_algo_st)

Comment: Interesting project! I know that most people don't like this kind of comment, but have you taken a look at professional solutions like [Platform Computing]( http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Computing)?

Comment: @jboi I want my own version of algorithm

Comment: Looking there means learning from them. They had the same problem and solved it in two ways. One is, that the JVM pulls for work when it's free. Second is a delay parameter that they do not run In an resonance catastrophe when runtimes of tasks and checking periods are equal. It's really worth looking ;-)

Comment: The JVM's need to report back when they are not busy anymore.  This is essentially a Pool.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are over thinking the problem. A simple strategy is to have a broker which is aware of all the pending tasks. Each task worker or thread asks the broker for a new message/task to work on. The broker gives out work in the order it was asked for.  This is how JMS queues works. For the JVMs which can handle two tasks you can start two threads.

There is many standard JMS which do this but I suggest looking at ActiveMQ as it is simple to get started with.

note in you case, a simpler solution is to have one machine with 8 GB of memory. You can buy 8 GB for a server for very little ($40 - $150 depending on vendor) and it will be used more efficiently in one instance by sharing resource.  I assume you are looking at much larger instances. Instances smaller than 8 GB are better off just upgrading it.

> How do I make sure that the machine I am currently returning is free

This is your scenario, if you don't know how to tell if a machine is free, I don't see how anyone would have more knowledge of you application.

> and if the machine is not free I allot the next machine with highest memory available.

You need to look at the free machines and pick the one with the most available memory.  I don't see what the catch is here other than doing what you have stated.

> I also have to make sure that the machine that is entitled to process X tasks, does process X tasks even that machine is currently busy.

You need a data source or store for this information.  What is allowed to run where. In JMS you would have multiple queues and only pass certain queues to the machines which can process those queue.

Comment: might be a better solution. But what I am looking is to make a change in this class itself

Comment: @saplingPro Since you are proposing something which you are the expert as it is non standard, you are the best person to answer those questions.  I can only suggest what you would do for a standard solution and you can use this as a guide.

Comment: There is a method named `cloudSimEventFired` inside the same class which tells when the machine is free.I am looking for an algorithm that can help me do it.

Comment: So when you attempt to allocate a vm, you reserve it and when it is freed, you unreserve it.

Comment: When I attempt to allocate a VM, I just make a `return` as seen in the `getNextAvailableVM()` method.After completion of the task, machine automatically gets freed and the event handler is notified which is the `cloudSimEventFired` method

Comment: Good, so what are you having trouble with?

Comment: I need to modify `getNextAvailableVM()` so that it supports the fact that if a machine is busy,allocate the task to the next machine having highest memory. I still haven't figured out, how can I do this

Comment: The allocations will still be in a round robin fashion but a `Next if Busy` clause is added. Also a machine that can handle,process 4 tasks will get only 4 tasks. After that the next machine in order will get the task

Comment: For example a machine with 2048 memory..`0` allocated,`0` allocated,`0` comes busy now....`1` is allocated..check if `0` is free..if free allocate `0`..if 0 had earlier processed 4 tasks ..`0` would only be considered in a fresh round-robin cycle

Comment: You start at the next machine giving slightly higher preference to non busy machines. How you do that is up to you but you could give each machine a score,  there number of tasks it can perform plus say 0.1 if it is non-busy.  Then you find the machine with the maximum score starting with the next one.  All things being equal, the next one is picked, however if there is machine with the same memory but not busy it will pick the first of those.

Comment: To do all that you need a counter to record which is next, a method to give you the score of each machine and loop to iterate over the machines to find the highest score.

Comment: can you please help me with the code. I have slightly modified the `cloudSimEventFired` method by implementing a `busyList` that is private to each object created of this class.

Comment: The number of objects created depends upon the number of Data Centers. For 5 Data Centers, 5 objects will be created and the application is multithreaded.So 5 threads can simultaneously call the methods of this class

Comment: Also..I have already given group of machines, with same memory/configuration a score which is by the name `weightCount`. This tells how many tasks a machine can perform. This attribute is defined inside the class `AlgoAttr`along with other attributes named `vmCount` and `requestAllocated`

Comment: I would make the allocation single threaded.  Making it multi-threaded and concurrent is 10x harder.  I would have each node tell you its score and it should be aware of how busy it is.  You can have a score like `allocated == 0 ? vmCount + 0.5 : vmCount - allocated` You don't need a busy list as well as this is built into the score.

Comment: allocation cannot be single threaded.The idea of multiple instances of this class comes from the fact that there are different data center brokers for different data center. So data center 1 will have broker-1 and DC-2 will have broker 2..

Comment: and then the allocation is done according to the *data center broker* policy selected earlier..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37450/discussion-between-saplingpro-and-peter-lawrey)

Comment: So how are you going to guarantee that two broker do not allocate to the same VM incorrectly?  I would assume each data centre broker is single threaded and will only allocate VMs in its data centre.

Comment: I left a query in the chat room